# Rails: Which is the preferred Mailchimp gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp

Which is the preferred gem or plugin for using the Mailchimp API with Rails?

There's a list here, but I have yet to try any:
[mailchimp ruby](http://www.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/#ruby)

Any feedback is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

With recent research, we found the gibbon gem to be a full featured and easy to use API wrapper for MailChimp. Hominid seems a bit more complex to use, and lacking in community discussion. The Gibbon gem is located at https://github.com/amro/gibbon

I found some great blog posts that describe how to get started with the Gibbon gem:

[Mailchimp Integration with Ruby on Rails](https://web.archive.org/web/20111019144700/http://www.leorodriguez.me/2011/08/mailchimp-integration-with-ruby-on.html)

[How to subscribe a member into MailChimp using Ruby On Rails](https://web.archive.org/web/20111020040702/http://www.leorodriguez.me/2011/08/subscribe-member-into-mailchimp-using.html)

[Email marketing for your rails app made easy with Mailchimp](https://web.archive.org/web/20120123023642/http://highgroove.com/articles/2011/10/18/email-marketing-for-your-rails-app-made-easy-with-mailchimp.html)

Answer (score 2):

These days Hominid is recommending the offical Mailchimp gem instead:
https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-ruby/

Comment: The official Mailchimp gem supports only v2 of the API which is deprecated. Gibbon supports the new API v3. So I guess that this recommendation is not valid (at the moment = 08/2015)

Comment: When I installed Gibbon today, I saw this message "IMPORTANT: Gibbon now targets MailChimp API 2.0, which is substantially different from API 1.3." ... So it seems it doesn't support v3?

Comment: Not sure about that message, but it seems to work just fine with v3. Did some testing today.

Answer (score 1):

Mailchimp has now released official clients for their Marketing API, Transactional API (Mandrill) and mobile SDKs , which can be found here: https://mailchimp.com/developer/tools/ - you can now also reach this page by following the OP's link and go to tools.

They currently support ruby, php, python and nodejs on the V3 API.