# Passing value from text_field_tag to application_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp

Edit: I've rewritten this question to be more specific.
So I have a log in box and what I'd like to do, is when the user presses the log in button, pass the value from text_field_tag to my application controller and set a variable there. I'm not sure how to do this, so I guess I'm asking how to link the view and controller together and then how to pass the value using parameters. Here's my view:

```
<% content_for :title, "Home" %>
<h2>MailChimp API Login</h2>
<%= form_tag do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag(:apikey) %>
  </p>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Log In", :name => "apikey" %></p>
<% end %>
```

and my application_controller:

```
require 'mailchimp'

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :setup_mcapi

  def setup_mcapi
    @mc = Mailchimp::API.new(params[:apikey])
  end
end
```

Comment: Other than implying you're doing something with email, give you pointers for **WHAT**? You've provided just enough info to imply you're doing something, but that's it. So... "pick a direction and start walking".

Comment: So my steps that I won't to follow are: 
- 1) dynamically connect to Mailchimp through API – create a 
dialogue box to enter API credentials

- 2) retrieve and select from available lists in Mailchimp

- 3) retrieve members of a list in mailchimp

- 4) export these members into an excel/CSV file

Comment: Sorry, but this question is just *way* too broad to be answered here.  Right now we might as well just suggest hiring someone to do this work.  Go research each individual issue, and post *specific* questions when you run into problems, and post the code you've tried.

Comment: Okay I've managed to get down to wanting to export a list from MailChimp. I have the pages set up and can view a list if I manually enter an API key. However I still don't know how to handle something like this. I assume it's in the application_controller.rb file? I've never touched rails before so I don't know what direction to head in.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below  links for mailchimp integration and reading mail list in Ruby on rails.

[rails on mailchimp by gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497908/rails-and-mailchimp?rq=1)

[Rails Plugin to access MailChimp and read list](https://github.com/amro/gibbon)

But, If you want me to explain in C#, then i can tell you point by point.